# Strip everything in string before the second “-” character that occurs?

Tags: php, string

I found solution for oposite:"Strip everything in string after the second “-” character that occurs?"

```
$newstr = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-', strpos($str, '-')+2));
```

Now, I need solution for "BEFORE" the second "-":

```
Today is - Friday and tomorrow is - Saturday
```

To be:

```
Saturday
```

I would like to do this with strstr(), if it is possible.

I tried something like:

```
$newstr = substr($str, 0, strstr($str, '-', strstr($str, '-')+2));
```

Didn't worked.

Comment: The second dash or the last dash?  If last is good, thats probably easier.

Comment: Second. I take example with two dashes, but it can be any number of dashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$testString = "Today is - Friday and tomorrow is - Saturday";
$newString = substr(strstr(substr(strstr($testString, "-"),1),"-"),1);
echo $newString;//print  Saturday
```

Find the substring after the first `-` and then find the substring after the first `-` within that.

Comment: Yep. Correct. I just can't realize those functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method using explode.

```
  $str = "Today is - Friday and tomorrow is - Saturday";
  $parts = explode("-", $str, 3);
  if (count($parts) == 3){
        $res = array_pop($parts);
  } else {
        // handle the case where there is no second delimiter.
        $res = "";
  }
  echo $res;
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 7. you wrote res instead $res on line 7. This is confusing for people who do not know coding well.

Comment: forgot a $ in the else clause

Comment: This working aswell. But I prefer first answer, coz I stared the way with substr().